# MS ACCESS & VBA Matching Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables, I want to match values in both tables/pairing fields as below

In table 1 records 1 and 2 should be updated in MatchRef field as matched
In table 2 records 1 and 2 should be updated in matchref field as matched

but in Table 1 the record 3 should not updated as matched as there is no matching field in table 2

Table 1

```
ID     MatchField     MatchValue      MatchRef
1      AAA            100
2      AAA            100
3      AAA            100
4      BBB            100
```

Table 2

```
ID     MatchField     MatchValue      MatchRef
1      AAA            100
2      AAA            100
4      BBB            100
```

Here ID is not an unique filed, its just auto number.

How to do it in Ms Access? There will be 600 000 records on average in each table and working on a Citrix environment.

Comment: hmmm... you show two tables with 4 column headers but only 3 column values -- what is up with that?

Comment: I don't understand why record 3 does not have a matching field -- the AAA is the same -- is it because there is no matching ID field?

Comment: In the matchref field is to update the comment as "Matched" The Logic is the 2 sets  AAA 100 records in Table 1 and 3 sets in Table 2. The two records in each table should be matched. in table 1 the third AAA 100 should be remain unmatched

Comment: Are you doing this with local Access tables, or do you have a SQL back-end? It's pretty easy to solve in SQL Server.

Comment: local access tables

Comment: You comment does not make sense -- you say there are 600 000 records -- clearly the ones you want to skip is not just the 3rd AAA record.  SO if you you can't use the ID field how do you know which ones not to match?

Comment: Ok, I will tell simply, I want to pair the records and update as "Matched" in matchref field. It's not necessary to find which record matched with which one. I want to get the record which doesnt have pair.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would find matching records as far as I can tell --

```
SELECT
  *
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
  AND T1.MATCHFIELD = T2.MATCHFIELD
```

Comment: ID field cannot be matched . ID field is an AutoNumber field

Comment: @ShivaganeshAnandaraja -- this is nothing about an AutoNumber field that stops it from being used in a join -- it might not be the correct thing to use according to your business rules -- but since you have explained those rules, there is no way for me to know what you are trying to do.